# How can i remove particular package of student exam test from database and open it after purchasing it only.i need code for it

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)MethodSendPaymentMail:(NSString *)Status
{
NSDictionary * dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           Status,@"status",
                           _dictPaymentDetail[@"orderid"],@"orderid",
                           [RKUtility sharedInstance].strUserId,@"studentid",
                           [[RKUtility sharedInstance].dictUserProfile objectForKey:@"name"],
                           @"studentname",
                           _dictPackageDetail[@"packageid"],@"packageid",
                           _dictPackageDetail[@"name"],@"packagename",
                           _dictPackageDetail[@"packagecost"],@"amount",
                           @"",@"payumoneyid",
                           [[RKUtility sharedInstance].dictUserProfile objectForKey:@"email"],@"emai",
                           nil];
objJSONParser=[[JSONParser alloc] init];
[objJSONParser parseData:dictionary WebServiceName:ServiceSendPaymentMail withBlock:^(NSMutableDictionary *dict3, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error==nil&&[dict3 count]>0)
     {

     }

 }];
 }
```

Comment: your question is not clear..

Comment: what you are not understand ?